# Ошибка сохранения: AttributeErroe: ‘CreateKarto’ object has no attribute ‘save’

Tags: python, django, form

Суть:  получить данные из формы и сохранить в один отдельный объект.
создал модель:

```
class Karto(models.Model):
    id_name = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    small = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

создал форму:

```
class CreateKarto(forms.Form):
    class Meta():
        model = Karto
        fields = ['small', 'file']
        widgets = {
            'small': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}),
        }
```

соответственно форма из шаблона:

```
<form action="/dokarto/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for name="small">Краткое содержание</label>
    <textarea name="small" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>    
    <input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
```

и вьюха:

```
def create_karto(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST and ("pause" not in request.session):
            form = CreateKarto(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instances = form.save()
                request.session.set_expiry(60)
                request.session['pause'] = True
                args['create_done'] = 1
                render_to_response('create_docsup.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                redirect('/docsup/', args)
        else:
            redirect('/docsup/', args)
    else:
        redirect('/docsup/', args)
```

Выдает ошибку

> AttributeErroe: ‘CreateKarto’ object has no attribute ‘save’
>   ругается на form.save()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateCarto` наследуется от `forms.Form` - то есть Вы создаете обычную форму. У нее нет метода `save()`. Вы лишь можете воспользоваться атрибутом `cleaned_data` и переписать оттуда информацию в свою модель.

Но в данном случае Вы скорее всего имели в виду `class CreateKarto(forms.ModelForm)` - тогда все будет работать: форма будет сохранять данные в новый объект.